# Else part is not executed if the 'if' condition is false

Tags: java, selenium

[image]I am trying to login an application and if the element in the 'if' condition is not present then it should execute the else part. Now it is not executing the else part. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).size() == 1) {
    if (scount <= 4)
        Login();
    else
        System.out.println(user);
} else {
    System.out.println("Login Passed");
}
```

Comment: Always, always use braces. Even when they are optional.

Comment: which if is true and which is false?

Comment: "Now it is not executing the else part" There are two: which one?

Comment: Which of these two `else` parts is not executed?

Comment: what did you write in Login(); and which else is not execute?

Comment: maybe your first line is throwing a NullPointerException

Comment: I think you are talking about inner `if-else`.Try using braces

Comment: Outer else is not executed. The second else part

Comment: Which else are you talking about? Possibly there are some exceptions

Comment: Let me explain you my question in detail. I am trying to login an application, if the login is failed, it should execute the 'if' part and if login is successful, it should execute the 'else' part(System.out.println("Login Passed")

Here if the login is failed, it throws some alert message whose path is (/html/body/div/form/div/div/span) which i have given in the if condition.

Comment: There could be some exception. Explain which else part is not executing.

Comment: Add sysout statement in below if condition. also add braces.It might be executing below condition                                                                                if (scount <= 4)
        Login();

Comment: @prity - The second else in which i have given  System.out.println("Login Passed") is not executed

Comment: What does your debugger show you when you single-step through the code?

Comment: @Bhuvana _it throws some alert message_ WebDriver `Alert`s have to be acknowledged. Probably code execution hangs in the `if`-stmt so the `else` block is not executed.

Comment: From what I know this kind of xpath "/html/body/div/form/div/div/span" is not recommended. Post also the html code and try a different xpath

Comment: @Kevin Anderson - When i debug the code by adding the break point at if condition, the execution of the code stops if i give correct username and password to login. I have attached the screenshot of my debug view, please check it.

Comment: @KevinAnderson From what you say, the problem is in `Login()` method. Onces you are in the second if `(scount<=4)` even if is true of false, you'll never get `System.out.println("Login Passed");` executed.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).size() == 1) {
    if (scount <= 4){
        Login();
    }else{
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}else{
        System.out.println("Login Passed");
    }
```

**Later Edit:** Add another if condition:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).size() == 1) {
        if (scount <= 4){
            if(Login()){
                System.out.println("Login Passed");
            }else{
                System.out.println("The username or password is incorrect !");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println(user);
        }
}else{
   System.out.println("Multiple xpath were found !");
}
```

Comment: I did not downvote but this is not an answer to the question. You just added braces which do not change code execution. But the question is about why some code is not executed. If the question was "How can I improve code readability using curly braces?", then the answer would be useful.

Comment: @Würgspaß You're right, I didn't tested his code first. Anyway I see no issue in the code logic, the only problem is that I don't recommend that kind of xpath.

Comment: @BOB - I have tried your code, but it shows error. Why you have taken login() in if condition. For your better understanding i have attached the login() code. Please check

Comment: How did you know when "Login has passed" and when "Login has not passed"? what are those conditions?

Comment: @BOB - If this element /html/body/div/form/div/div/span is present then login is failed and if it is not present then the login is passed.Because  /html/body/div/form/div/div/span this is the element which exists only if the login is failed.

Comment: @Bhuvana Ok, then just write something like this:    `if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).size() >= 1) {System.out.println("Login has failed !"); }else{
                Login();
            }`